# Testing a Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures

I am reading Skiena's "The Algorithm Design Manual" for personal learning, and I am trying to implement the linked list in C.

How do I use the `insert_list()` function and then print out my list to verify the values?

```
/* definition of linked list */
typedef struct list {
    int item;
    struct list *next;
} list;
/* insert item into list */
void insert_list(list **l, int x) {
    list *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item = x;
    p->next = *l;
    *l = p;
}
```

I wrote a main function to try and figure out how to use `insert_list()`:

```
int main(void) {
    struct list *root;
struct list *traverse;
    root = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    root->next = 0;
    root->item = 5;
    traverse = root;
    insert_list(traverse, 1);    /* this is the problem */
    printf("%d\n", root->item);
}
```

I receive an error at compilation with gcc:
`expected 'struct list **' but argument is of type 'struct list *`

How do I properly use this function to insert items into and then print my list? Without the insert_list() call, it prints root->item as 5, as expected.

Comment: insert_list(&traverse, 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nice function. Now: use it.

---

```
int main(void) {
    // You have a typedef, so you should omit the struct keyword
    /*struct */ list *root= NULL, *p;

    insert_list(&root, 5);    
    insert_list(&root, 1);

    for (p=root; p; p=p->next){
      printf("%d\n", p->item);
      }

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the way to get it to compile is to change the call to `insert_list()` to this:

```
insert_list(&traverse, 1);
```

The `insert_list()` function takes a pointer *to a pointer* to a `struct list`, not just a pointer to a `struct list`.

You've written the code in an odd way. You're first assigning `traverse` to be equal to `root` and then calling the `insert_list()` function, which will overwrite `traverse` with the pointer to the new node it creates. At that point, the new node will be the "root" of your tree, not the `root` node you originally created. This will likely cause confusion when you attempt to traverse the list later.